# Django deployment error deango.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: django, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Hey i have an django application which is working fine locally but its not working when it is hosted on a web showing below error

**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading pyodbc module: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so**)

Did i miss anything at the time of hosting?

Comment: Did you get the error during deployment or launching the application? How did you deploy the application? Did you use DevOps? Did you use python3.7 locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you got this issue during deployment via DevOps pipeline, you could specify an exact version of python in the [UsePythonVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version?view=azure-devops) (including minor version) task.

Supported python versions, you could check the software of the agent image:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software

Also, you could try the solution in the following case, by adding deadsnakes repo, installing 3.7 and symlink python to python3.7:

https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2634#issuecomment-775808754

Comment: How's your issue going? Is your issue solved?